# Create a custom dropdown icon in the quill editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a quill editor where I need to have a drop down when a custom toolbar icon is clicked

The icon can be U icon as detailed in the example code. But when U icon of the quill toolbar is clicked it should show the dropdown menu and when one of the item is clicked it would make it uppercase or lowercase or surround the text with <<>>

I have tried with

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.7/quill.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.7/quill.bubble.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.7/quill.snow.css"></link>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/T-vK/DynamicQuillTools@master/DynamicQuillTools.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Upper case</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lower case</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Surround with <<>></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


  <div id="editor"></div>
  <script>
    // Create a Quill Editor instance with some built-in toolbar tools
    const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow',
        modules: {
            toolbar: {
                container: [
                    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

                    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
                    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                    [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
                    [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
                    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],

                    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
                    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

                    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                    [{ 'font': [] }],
                    [{ 'align': [] }],
                    ['clean'],
                ]
            }
        }
    })

    // Add a custom Button to the Quill Editor's toolbar:
    const myButton = new QuillToolbarButton({
    icon: `<svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,3V9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4,4H9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4-4V3"></path></svg>`
    })
   
    myButton.onClick = function(quill) {
        const { index, length } = quill.selection.savedRange
        const selectedText = quill.getText(index, length)
        const newText = selectedText.toUpperCase()
        quill.deleteText(index, length)
        quill.insertText(index, newText)
        quill.setSelection(index, newText.length)
    }
    myButton.attach(quill)

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1817 discusses adding a custom dropdown. There's a linked JSFiddle that kind of gets things working. It appears that you might be able to use that and just add custom HTML for the button if you override some of the quill styles.

Comment: Thanks JasonB This is not the one I was looking for, I wanted to implement using a bootstrap dropdown.